Spotify API - status: 403, code:-1 - Insufficient client scope, reason: None
Everytime I run the following code it keeps giving me the same error, however it was working 5 mins ago, all that changed was me going to the bathroom and then coming back to change variable names
username = '9qk7akrruah30sd2qix0x4lmp'
client_id = 'c97fbdbd18674cf3851def089d654a65'
client_secret = '{My Client Secret}'
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:80'

# Set up Spotify API client with client ID, secret, and redirect URI
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(
    client_id=client_id,
    client_secret=client_secret,
    redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
    scope="user-library-read"  # Add the required scopes here
))

# Get the access token
access_token_info = sp.auth_manager.get_access_token(as_dict=False)

# Print the access token
print(access_token_info)

def create_playlist_with_recommendations(type, id, playlist_name='Recommendeded Playlist'):
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=access_token_info, auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,
                                                                      client_secret=client_secret,
                                                                      redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                                                                      scope='playlist-modify-public'))

    # Get similar tracks
    # Get similar tracks
    if type == "track":
        similar_tracks = sp.recommendations(seed_tracks=[id], limit=10)['tracks']
    elif type == "artist":
        similar_tracks = sp.recommendations(seed_artists=[id], limit=10)['tracks']
    
    # Extract track URIs from similar tracks
    track_uris = [track['uri'] for track in similar_tracks]

    # Create a new playlist
    playlist = sp.user_playlist_create(user=username, name=playlist_name, public=False)

    # Add tracks to the playlist
    sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=playlist['id'], items=track_uris)

    return playlist

playlist = create_playlist_with_recommendations("track", "6UBjSnyP1O5W5ndJoO9vUk") # Night Moves - Bob Seger
playlist = create_playlist_with_recommendations("artist", "3qBdT7NKSOBogHhGiUVLiV") # Radio Company - country rock

> HTTP Error for POST to https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/9qk7akrruah30sd2qix0x4lmp/playlists with Params: {} returned 403 due to Insufficient client scope
> {
    "name": "SpotifyException",
    "message": "http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/9qk7akrruah30sd2qix0x4lmp/playlists:
 Insufficient client scope, reason: None",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
File ~\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\spotipy\\client.py:271, in Spotify._internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    266 response = self._session.request(
    267     method, url, headers=headers, proxies=self.proxies,
    268     timeout=self.requests_timeout, **args
    269 )
--> 271 response.raise_for_status()
    272 results = response.json()

File ~\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\requests\\models.py:1021, in Response.raise_for_status(self)
   1020 if http_error_msg:
-> 1021     raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)

HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/9qk7akrruah30sd2qix0x4lmp/playlists

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SpotifyException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[10], line 26
     23     return playlist
     25 #playlist = create_playlist_with_recommendations(\"track\", \"6UBjSnyP1O5W5ndJoO9vUk\") # Night Moves - Bob Seger
---> 26 playlist = create_playlist_with_recommendations(\"artist\", \"3qBdT7NKSOBogHhGiUVLiV\") # Radio Company - country rock

Cell In[10], line 18, in create_playlist_with_recommendations(type, id, playlist_name)
     15 track_uris = [track['uri'] for track in similar_tracks]
     17 # Create a new playlist
---> 18 playlist = sp.user_playlist_create(user=username, name=playlist_name, public=False)
     20 # Add tracks to the playlist
     21 sp.playlist_add_items(playlist_id=playlist['id'], items=track_uris)

File ~\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\spotipy\\client.py:818, in Spotify.user_playlist_create(self, user, name, public, collaborative, description)
    802 \"\"\" Creates a playlist for a user
    803 
    804     Parameters:
   (...)
    809         - description - the description of the playlist
    810 \"\"\"
    811 data = {
    812     \"name\": name,
    813     \"public\": public,
    814     \"collaborative\": collaborative,
    815     \"description\": description
    816 }
--> 818 return self._post(\"users/%s/playlists\" % (user,), payload=data)

File ~\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\spotipy\\client.py:328, in Spotify._post(self, url, args, payload, **kwargs)
    326 if args:
    327     kwargs.update(args)
--> 328 return self._internal_call(\"POST\", url, payload, kwargs)

File ~\\anaconda3\\Lib\\site-packages\\spotipy\\client.py:293, in Spotify._internal_call(self, method, url, payload, params)
    286         reason = None
    288     logger.error(
    289         'HTTP Error for %s to %s with Params: %s returned %s due to %s',
    290         method, url, args.get(\"params\"), response.status_code, msg
    291     )
--> 293     raise SpotifyException(
    294         response.status_code,
    295         -1,
    296         \"%s:\
 %s\" % (response.url, msg),
    297         reason=reason,
    298         headers=response.headers,
    299     )
    300 except requests.exceptions.RetryError as retry_error:
    301     request = retry_error.request

SpotifyException: http status: 403, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/9qk7akrruah30sd2qix0x4lmp/playlists:
 Insufficient client scope, reason: None"
}


However this works perfectly:
def get_favourites(item_type, time_range='short_term', limit=10):
    # Set up Spotify API client with access token
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=client_id,
                                                   client_secret=client_secret,
                                                   redirect_uri=redirect_uri,
                                                   scope='user-top-read'))

    # Validate item_type
    if item_type not in ['tracks', 'artists']:
        raise ValueError("Invalid item_type. Must be 'tracks' or 'artists'.")

    # Get the user's top items
    if item_type == 'tracks':
        top_items = sp.current_user_top_tracks(
            time_range=time_range, limit=limit)
        # Extract relevant information from the tracks
        items_info = []
        for item in top_items['items']:
            item_info = {
                'name': item['name'],
                'artist': item['artists'][0]['name'],
                'album': item['album']['name'],
                'popularity': item['popularity'],
                'id': item['id']
            }
            items_info.append(item_info)
    elif item_type == 'artists':
        top_items = sp.current_user_top_artists(
            time_range=time_range, limit=limit)
        # Extract relevant information from the artists
        items_info = []
        for item in top_items['items']:
            item_info = {
                'name': item['name'],
                'id': item['id'],
                'genres': item['genres'],
                'popularity': item['popularity']
            }
            items_info.append(item_info)

    return items_info


# Example usage
top_tracks = get_favourites(item_type='tracks')
for track in top_tracks:
    print(f"Track ID: {track['id']}\nTrack: {track['name']} - Artist: {track['artist']} - Album: {track['album']} - Popularity: {track['popularity']}\n")

top_artists = get_favourites(item_type='artists')
for artist in top_artists:
    print(
        f"Artist ID: {artist['id']}\nArtist: {artist['name']} - Genres: {', '.join(artist['genres'])} - Popularity: {artist['popularity']}\n")

I've reran the code to make the playlist recommeder several times, ive gotten fresh code from google and chatGPT but to no avail, I've tried running it on different ides, creating a new project on the Spotify WebAPI dashboard and nada.
Can anyone figure this out? I'm losing my mid lol

I've also tried using 'playlist-modify-public-playlist-modify-private' to no avail in the scope

You can click edit under your question to add details rather than commenting.

"playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private" or "playlist-modify-public-playlist-modify-private"?

I see you define sp.Spotify() twice. Tip: you can use sp that is outside of a function, inside the function by adding global sp at the top of that function.

You have to watch out the scope which does not seem to be appropriate for what you are trying to do. We can actually see that the code that works does not have the same scope as the one which doesn't. 
Since you are trying to modify playlist, you should use :
sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=SpotifyOAuth(client_id=os.getenv('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_ID'),
                                               client_secret=os.getenv('SPOTIFY_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                                               redirect_uri=os.getenv('SPOTIFY_REDIRECT_URI'),
                                               scope='playlist-modify-public'))

It can be public or private regarding the type of playlist you are trying to create/modify.
You can watch out Spotify documentation regarding scopes, this might help :
https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/concepts/scopes
